# Google Geocoding Result into MVC Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, google-maps-api-3

I am utilizing the JavaScript API v3. I am basically geocoding an address as follows:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    //Get results array here
}
```

This is working successfully. I now need to pass that JSON to an MVC controller. I have seen numerous ways to do this, but I cannot get it working with the Geocode result.

From [Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx): (I have a collection on objects that duplicate the structure of the result. At the outermost object being a `result[]` (see below)).

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    var jsonT = JSON.stringify(results);           
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ctrl/Action',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonT,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.Result);
        }
    });
}
```

The controller method fires, however the value is always `null`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(GoogleGeoCodeResponse geoResponse)
    {
        //geoResponse is always null
        return View();
    }
```

**My Google Class(s)**

```
[Serializable]
public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse
{
    //public string status { get; set; }
    public results[] results { get; set; }

}
[Serializable]
public class results
{
    public string[] types { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public address_component[] address_components { get; set; }
    public geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string partial_match { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class address_component
{
    public string[] types { get; set; }
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class geometry
{
    public location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public viewport viewport { get; set; }
    public bounds bounds { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class location
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class viewport
{
    public southwest southwest { get; set; }
    public northeast northeast { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class bounds
{
    public southwest southwest { get; set; }
    public northeast northeast { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class southwest
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class northeast
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tearing my hair out, I took a break and came back to find the issue right away with the help of @Darin Dimitrov help. The problem was that the JSON was not matching the object. The `GoogleGeoCodeResponse` object has an array of `results` called results, however the JSON returned from Google has an array of results but it is not named. Adding this before my `stringify` adds the proper naming structures and all bound well.

```
var o = { results: results };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have added a JSON value provider factory in `Application_Start`:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

and the actual JSON request matches your view model signature:

```
{ geoResponse: { 
    results: [ 
        { types: [ 't1', 't2' ], formatted_address: 'abc', ... }, 
        { types: [ 't3', 't4' ], formatted_address: 'def', ... }, 
        ...
    ] } 
}
```

you should successfully get the view model in the controller action. Also you probably don't need to decorate your models with the `[Serializable]` as that's not used by XML and JSON serializers. It's used for binary serialization.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find my answer. Noting that `geoResponse` was not right, but that my JSON also was wrong got me down the right track.